# How to make asyncRestemplate to make fire and forget call?

Tags: java, spring, rest-client

I am trying to make rest call , in which I don't want response.

```
    AsyncRestTemplate asycTemp = new AsyncRestTemplate();
            ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = asycTemp.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType);
                //waits for the result
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = future.get();

}
```

Here future.get() is holding the thread till it receives the response. Here I want to release the thread immediately after making the rest call. Is there any other like asyncresttemplate?

Comment: Won't it become "fire and forget" if you don't wait for the result, i.e. just don't call future.get()? This may depend on the implementation of AsyncRestRemplate.exchange(...).

Comment: ok. But When I am not adding future.get().. the rest call is not happening.

Comment: Try passing what you have to CompletableFuture.runAsync(). Call the "get()" on your future, but not on the resulting CompletableFuture. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @sen if your program terminated immediately after execute exchange, sleep some seconds then rest call is happening.